# I need to make an aggregation in Power Query, by choosing value based on condition

Tags: powerquery, aggregation

Here's an example of my data:
[image]

For the same ID, I need to check if the increase/decrease was on the same date as the creation.
If yes then yes if no add no if there is just a creation date add ok. We can get rid of ID's with values no. Create a NewPay column with Pay that is associated with increase/decrease if there is only creation just populate the Pay value.

The outcome I expect:
[image]

Here's the outcome I got
[image]

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Pay", Int64.Type}, {"Event", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Event]), "Event", "Date"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"ID"}, {{"creationmax", each List.Max([creation]), type nullable datetime}, {"increasemax", each List.Max([increase]), type nullable datetime}, {"decreasemax", each List.Max([decrease]), type nullable datetime}, {"all", each _, type table [ID=nullable number, Pay=nullable number, creation=nullable datetime, increase=nullable datetime, decrease=nullable datetime]}}),
#"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", {"Pay"}, {"Pay"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded all", "Custom", each if ([increasemax]=null and [decreasemax]=null) then "ok" else if ([creationmax]=[increasemax] or [creationmax]=[decreasemax]) then "yes" else "no"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] <> "no")),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {"ID", "Pay", "Custom"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "NewPay", each if [Custom] = "ok" then [Pay] else if ([Custom] = "yes" and ([Attribute] = "increasemax" or [Attribute] = "decreasemax")) then [Pay] else null)
in
#"Added Custom1"
```

I have a problem with NewPay value

Comment: Please add your data as copiable text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need some of the columns, but if I understand your data setup correctly, you can do this all within a `Table.Group` function.

*BTW, I guessed that your `Pay` column in your desired results table should reflect the intial Pay.*

Given your initial data, here is one method:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Pay", Int64.Type}, {"Event", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Records", (t)=> if List.Count(List.Distinct(t[Date]))= 1 
            then Record.FromList(
                {t[Pay]{0}, 
                if List.Last(t[Event]) = "creation" then "ok" else "Yes",
                List.Last(t[Event]) & "max", 
                t[Date]{0}, 
                List.Last(t[Pay])},
                {"Pay","Custom","Attribute","Value","NewPay"})
            else null}}),
    #"Remove Nulls" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each[Records] <>  null),
    #"Expanded Records" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Remove Nulls", "Records", 
        {"Pay", "Custom", "Attribute", "Value", "NewPay"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Records",{{"Pay", Int64.Type}, {"Custom", type text}, {"Attribute", type text}, {"Value", type date}, {"NewPay", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote for managing to understanding the ask, with nice solution

Comment: @horseyride Thanks. I made some assumptions. We'll see if they're correct.