# I need to make a custom aggregation in Power Query, by choosing maximum but based on condition

Tags: powerquery, aggregation

I don't seem to understand how to create custom aggregation, please assist.
That's the question I asked before, quite similar
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444245/i-need-to-make-an-aggregation-in-power-query-by-choosing-value-based-on-conditi](https://stackoverflow.com)

Here's my problem:
If a user has any *saving* the *rate* for this user should be a maximum and saved as a *NewRate* else just leave *rate*. One user will have only one row with saving.

Example:

| ID | ... | Rate | Saving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 600 | yes |
| 1 | ... | 500 | no |
| 2 | ... | 400 | no |
| 3 | ... | 300 | no |
| 4 | ... | 300 | yes |
| 4 | ... | 500 | no |

expected

| ID | ... | Rate | Saving | NewRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 600 | yes | 600 |
| 1 | ... | 500 | no | 600 |
| 2 | ... | 400 | no | 400 |
| 3 | ... | 300 | no | 300 |
| 4 | ... | 300 | yes | 500 |
| 4 | ... | 500 | no | 500 |

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type4", {"ID"}, {
    {"Records", (t) => 
        if List.Contains(t[Saving], "yes") 
        then Record.FromList([NewRate] = List.Max(t[Rate]))
        else Record.FromList([NewRate] = t[Rate])
        }
        })
```

Comment: Are you wanting all the rows to be returned or just one row per ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"data", each  Table.AddColumn(_, "NewRate", (x)=> if  List.Contains([Saving],"yes") then List.Max([Rate]) else x[Rate]), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Rate", "Saving", "NewRate"}, {"Rate", "Saving", "NewRate"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{
    "data",  each
    let a=_, 
    b= List.Max(a[Rate]),
    c= List.Contains(a[Saving],"yes")
    in Table.AddColumn(a, "NewRate", each if c then b else [Rate]),  type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Rate", "Saving", "NewRate"}, {"Rate", "Saving", "NewRate"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```